# Firestore: When do I have to remove SnapshotListeners?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an Android App and a few of my activities are listening to a Firestore-Database with the help of the function `addSnapshotListener`. When an activity that called the `addSnapshotListener` function gets finished (by calling `finish()` or pressing the back button): Is the listener removed automatically or do I have to call the `remove()` method myself?

And what happens when I start another activity? Is the SnapshotListner of the previous activity still active or is it paused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore never automatically removes listeners and is not aware of your app's activity lifecycle.  You have to remove them yourself.

The only time a listener is automatically removed is when your application's process is terminated - all of its code ceases to run at that point.

The exception to this is when passing an Activity argument to [addSnapshotListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#addSnapshotListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot%3E)).

Comment: Firestore listeners actually take an optional `Activity` parameter. If you pass that value, the listener will be removed during the `onStop` of that activity. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#addSnapshotListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot%3E)